# ¿hay solucion a este error de las texturas de mi juego 2d en android?

Tags: android, unity2d, game

[image]

necesito ayuda con este error en los sprites de mi juego, no se que pasa y creia que podria ser el paquete que añadi a unity "universal rp" no si si tendra que ver con algo por favor alguien que me diga la solucion

Comment: aunque muy tarde la respuesta, se ve como que falta limpiar la pantalla entre movimientos para que no se quede dibujado lo que ya pasó...